# Synchronize async actions with RxJS

Tags: rxjs5

I want to understand more of the RxJS concept. Here is the problem I am currently struggling with. I want to abstract the accesses to a DB with async calls and i want to synchronize the accesses.

Can i have a stream of actions,
 - that do async calls to db
 - i want the next action be delayed until the previous action is completed
 - the caller of the action shall get an Observable for the result of the async actions.

Example:

User of class calls Action1: Read DB item, calculate next state (e.g. increment field), write to DB
then..
User of class calls next actions (Action2), but Action1 is still in progress.
Action2: Read DB (shall not be started before the Action1:write is finished)

How can this be done with RxJS+Typescript?

Frank

/////////////////////////////////

Meanwhile i have this code:

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';

var actionQueue = new Rx.Subject< () => Rx.Observable<any>>();
actionQueue
  .concatMap( v => v() )
  .subscribe( v => {});

// example action with result type number
function action1 ( v : number ) : Rx.Observable<number> {
  console.log( ':: action1: ', v );
  var res = new Rx.Subject<number>();
  actionQueue.next( () => {
    console.log( '>> action1: ', v );
    setTimeout( ()=>{
      console.log( '<< action1: ', v );
      res.next(v);
      res.complete();
    }, 500 );
    return res;
  });
  return res;
}

// some actions enqueue now, after 700+2500ms
action1( 11 ).subscribe( v => console.log( 'XX action1: ', v ));
action1( 22 ).subscribe( v => console.log( 'XX action1: ', v ));
action1( 33 ).subscribe( v => console.log( 'XX action1: ', v ));

setTimeout( ()=>{
  action1( 44 ).subscribe( v => console.log( 'XX action1: ', v ));
}, 700 );

setTimeout( ()=>{
  action1( 55 ).subscribe( v => console.log( 'XX action1: ', v ));
}, 2500 );
```

The output shows that it does sequential stuff.
As typescript/js noob... is this code having pitfalls? Is there a more elegant way?

Frank

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `delayWhen()` operator?

```ts
// Observable wrapping action1.
const obsAction1 = Observable.create(observer => {
  // Read DB item
  // Calculate next state
  // Write to DB
  // Then:
  observer.complete();
});

// Private observable wrapping action2.
// DO NOT subscribe to it directly.
const _obsAction2 = Observable.create(observer => {
  // Read DB
  // Then:
  observer.complete();
});

// Public observable wrapping action2 AND delayed by action 1.
// This is what the client code should subscribe to.
const obsAction2 = _obsAction2.delayWhen(obsAction1);
```

Now the code consuming the observables:

```ts
obsAction1.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

// Values will be received only when `obsAction1` emits or completes.
obsAction2.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```